# is taking the transpose of a matrix a continuous operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, continuity

Suppose $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of matrices with $\lim_{i\to\infty}A_i= B$. Then does  $\lim_{i\to \infty}A_i^\top= B^\top$ if we measure distances between matrices with a 2-norm?

Comment: Only reading your question text, I have no idea what you are asking or what this has to do with the title. And considering only the title: this depends on the topology for which you are asking this question.

Comment: The expression $A\to B$ doesn't make a lot of sense in isolation.  Probably you mean $A$ to be a sequence of matrices, so let's say $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is that sequence.  Then in a metric topology on matrices we could define continuity of the transpose operation by saying $\lim_{i\to\infty} A_i = B$ implies $\lim_{i\to\infty} A_i^T = B^T$.

Comment: @hardmath yes thank you, this is what I mean more precisely. I will edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Now the question is still which topology we are talking about. To talk about limits, we need to know, e.g. how do you define *distance* between matrices. If one of the current answers fit your definition of distance, I recommend to include this definition into your question *and* to accept this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's continuous but depends on how you want to measure distance, i.e., what topology you choose (based on @M. Winter's comment).

For starters, consider $\|\cdot\|_2$. Let $\|A - B\|_2 < \delta$. Then for continuity, we want $\|A^T - B^T\|_2 < \epsilon$ for given $\epsilon$. Based on @user284331's answer we see that we can take $\delta = \epsilon$ because the 2-norm looks at all of the matrix's entries (and intuitively weights them the same). As an example of a different weighting, consider the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm.

However, on finite dimensional spaces, all norms are equivalent, so we can find an appropriate $\delta, \epsilon$ pair from this for any norm topology.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\|A\|=\left\{\displaystyle\sum|a_{i,j}|^{2}\right\}^{1/2}$, the transpose is just a rearrangement of elements of $A$, so it is clear that $\|A^{T}\|=\|A\|$, so the continuity can be reasoned as @jjjjjj did.